# Set Custom Response Body for 301 Redirect in IIS

Tags: iis, iis-7, iis-6, xss, pci-compliance

While bringing a site into PCI Compliance, I've encountered a reported vulnerability with IIS6 301 redirects when responding with a 301 redirect like this:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Thu, 15 May 2014 18:37:36 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 251
Location: http://www.xxxxxx.com/no5_such3_file7.pl?"><script>alert(12345);</script>
<html><body>
The requested resource was moved. It could be found here: 
<a href="http://www.xxxxxx.com/no5_such3_file7.pl?"><script>alert(12345);</script>">
http://www.xxxxxx.com/no5_such3_file7.pl?><script>alert(12345);</script></a>
</body></html>
```

According to the PCI scan, this could allow for script injection in browsers that don't ignore the body of the response upon encountering the 'location' header.

In order to fix this, I figure I could either add/alter redirection rules to filter potentially dangerous text from the querystring (which I don't really want to do) or alter the text that is sent in the body for a 301 redirect. I'd much rather just not send anything in the body of the response than try accounting for attacks in my redirection rules. How can I customize the text returned in the body for a 301 redirect? I have attempted adding a custom error page via IIS but it doesn't seem support that method of customization for 301's. I need this to work in IIS6 currently and IIS7+ in the near future, so any solutions that apply to either or both versions are welcome.

Edit-- Additionally, could this have SEO consequences? I assume Google and the like ignore the response body for 301 redirects the same as most browsers, but I would like to avoid being penalized for excluding a response body.

Answer (score 0):

I've bumped this as I was interested in doing the same thing.

I ended up using an [Outbound rule](https://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-outbound-rules-for-url-rewrite-module) to alter the body so that any pertinent IP addresses etc where removed.

Still be interested to know if there's something better.